# $\bf{\mu}_i$ and $\bf{\mu}_j$ have the same dimension, can I derive...?

Tags: matrices

If the vectors $\bf{\mu}_i$ and $\bf{\mu}_j$ have the same dimension, can I derive that 
$$\mu_1^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1-\mu_2^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_2=(\mu_1^T-\mu_2^T)\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1-\mu_2)$$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(\mu_1^T-\mu_2^T)\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1-\mu_2) = \mu_1^T \Sigma^{-1}\mu_1 
+ \mu_2^T \Sigma^{-1}\mu_2 - \mu_2^T \Sigma^{-1}\mu_1 - \mu_1^T \Sigma^{-1}\mu_2.$

In general, this does not equal the left hand side.

Here is an example:

Let $\mu_1 = (1,2)^T$, $\mu_2=(1,3)^T$, $\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&4\end{pmatrix}$.

$\mu_1^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1-\mu_2^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_2=-\frac{5}{4} $

$(\mu_1^T-\mu_2^T)\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1-\mu_2)=\frac{1}{4}$